# Issue with strtotime() and Meta Box date

Tags: date, translation

Shouldn't this code display the date provided from the META BOX date picker input field according to the language chosen?

Explanation:

The Meta Box value that is coming in though `rwmb_meta()` is always dd.mm.y, e.g. 06.02.16. So according to the language tags it should change the format (it does) and the (internationalizedly) right language of the date (not important in this example since it's all numbers, but it will be). But it always shows the current time...

Why? And how can I fix it?

```
<?php 

    $entered_start = rwmb_meta( "exhibition_meta_beginn" );

    _e("[:en]".date_i18n("m/d/y",strtotime($entered_start))."[:de]".date_i18n("d.m.y",strtotime($entered_start))."[:]");

    ?>–<?php

    $entered_end = rwmb_meta( "exhibition_meta_ende" );

    _e("[:en]".date_i18n("m/d/y",strtotime($entered_end))."[:de]".date_i18n("d.m.y",strtotime($entered_end))."[:]");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `strtotime` didn't recognise the date format `d.m.y`. `m/d-y` is save. Then it worked.